# Optimize this loop with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numerical-methods

Generating 5 millions points `r[i]` recursively with:

```
import numpy as np
n, a, b, c = 5000000, 0.0000002, 0.5, 0.4
eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
sigma = np.ones(n) * np.sqrt(a)
r = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(1,n):
    sigma[i] = np.sqrt(a + b * r[i-1] ** 2 + c * sigma[i-1] ** 2)
    r[i] = sigma[i] * eps[i]
```

uses approximatively 17 seconds on my standard i5 laptop computer.

I have used Cython quite often in the past and I know that using it here would probably optimize by a factor 10 < k < 100.

But before having to use Cython in such cases, I was wondering: **would there be a plain Numpy/Python method that I don't know that would optimize this much?**

Comment: When the `ith` value depends on the `ith-1` we try to use `cumsum`, `cumprod`, and other `ufunc.accumulate` functions.  Can your expression be cast into that form?  In that sense this is more of a math series problem than a `numpy` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply changing it to `math.sqrt` instead of `np.sqrt` gives you about 40% speedup here.

Since I'm quite a numba fanatic I tried the numba version versus your one (`initial`) and the math-one (`normal`)

```
import numpy as np
import math
import numba as nb
n, a, b, c = 500000, 0.0000002, 0.5, 0.4
eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
sigma = np.ones(n) * np.sqrt(a)
r = np.zeros(n)

def initial(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma, r):
    for i in range(1,n):
        sigma[i] = np.sqrt(a + b * r[i-1] ** 2 + c * sigma[i-1] ** 2)
        r[i] = sigma[i] * eps[i]

def normal(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma, r):
    for i in range(1,n):
        sigma[i] = math.sqrt(a + b * r[i-1] ** 2 + c * sigma[i-1] ** 2)
        r[i] = sigma[i] * eps[i]

@nb.njit
def function(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma, r):
    for i in range(1,n):
        sigma[i] = math.sqrt(a + b * r[i-1] ** 2 + c * sigma[i-1] ** 2)
        r[i] = sigma[i] * eps[i]
```

Then just to verify the results are the same:

```
sigma1 = sigma.copy()
sigma2 = sigma.copy()
sigma3 = sigma.copy()
r1 = r.copy()
r2 = r.copy()
r3 = r.copy()

initial(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma1, r1)   
normal(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma2, r2)       
function(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma3, r3)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(sigma1, sigma2)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(sigma1, sigma3)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(r1, r2)
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(r1, r3)
```

Well what about speed (I used n=500000 to have some faster timeit results):

```
%timeit initial(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma1, r1)   
1 loop, best of 3: 7.27 s per loop
%timeit normal(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma2, r2)   
1 loop, best of 3: 4.49 s per loop    
%timeit function(n, a, b, c, eps, sigma3, r3)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop
```

I know you didn't want cython so numba is probably also out of the question but the speedup is amazing (410 times faster!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally managed to make `numba` working! A little strange thing though : doing `eps = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, n)` *inside* `@nb.njit` `def function(...):` doesn't work : Invalid usage of Function(np.random.normal) with parameters (float64, float64, int32)
Known signatures:
 * (float64, float64) -> float64
 * (float64,) -> float64

Comment: Numba is still experimental. Most (or even all) math and numpy mathematical functions work inside a numba-function but everything else ... I don't know. I would use numba functions only for the actual computation and let a wrapper or external function create the result template or intermediate arrays.

Comment: @Basj It seems like ``numba.random.normal`` only supports two arguments (log and scale): See [Reference API](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.9/modules/numba.random.html#numba.random.random.normal). So you cannot create a whole array in one go maybe you need to create a ``np.zeros`` array and fill it with single ``random`` values. :-)

Comment: oh this means that using `np.random.normal` is automatically re-interpreted into `numba.radom.normal`?

Comment: Yes (but of course only inside the decorated function). You can check what is done (compiled code) by calling ``function_name.inspect_types()``

Answer (score 1):

Here I've factored out some terms, so it should run faster

```
sigma2 = np.ones(n)*a
eps2 = eps**2
eps2[0] = 0
abc = b*eps2+c
for i in range(1,n):
    #sigma2[i] = a + b * sigma2[i-1]*eps2[i-1] + c * sigma2[i-1]
    sigma2[i] = a + abc[i-1]*sigma2[i-1]
print np.sqrt(sigma2)
print np.allclose(sigma, np.sqrt(sigma2))
print np.sqrt(sigma2*eps2)  # r
```

I tried to factor out the `a+`, but haven't quite gotten the results to match.  If I could do that, I think could replace the loop with

```
np.cumprod(abc)
```

Comment: actually i don't get the same results with your operation as with the one the OP posted, I'm not sure why ... some element have the wrong sign. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, though.